# How to perform searches through parent and child dataframes

Tags: r, function, dataframe, search

I have a question about iterative lookup. I am trying to pull text out of an text database (an ontology) which relates words to each other so that when I lookup one word it gives me all the child words (eg "endoscopy" will give me all the subtypes of endoscopy eg "colonoscopy","gastroscopy" etc).

When I look up the word , I get a dataframe back with all the related words. I then want to lookup all of these words in the returned dataframe and see their related children words etc until the search is exhausted. In order to provide a minimal reproducible example I have three dataframes as follows: The first dataframe is the return from the original lookup query (how the lookup is done is not relevant so this function details are not included)

```
Numsdf1<-c("C123","C456","C789")
Textdf1<-c("Harry","Bobby","Terry")
df1<-data.frame(Numsdf1,Textdf1,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

The second dataframe is the result of looking up the string `"C123"`

```
NumsC123<-c("Coo","Noo","Too")
TextC123<-c("Tim","Slim","Shim")
C123<-data.frame(NumsC123,TextC123,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

The third dataframe is a result of looking up `"Coo"`

```
NumsCoo<-c("S144","S199","S743")
TextCoo<-c("Ellie","Bellie","Tellie")
Coo<-data.frame(NumsCoo,TextCoo,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

The fourth is the result of looking up `"Noo"`

```
NumsNoo<-c("GHS","THE","PAA")
TextNoo<-c("Front","Bunt","Shunt")
Noo<-data.frame(NumsNoo,TextNoo,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

And nothing is returned when looking up `"Too"`

I havent included the rest of the lookups for brevity.

I want to therefore derive a function that searches each table until it has a dataframe returned and if a dataframe is returned, then this is used to search. Once the searched dataframe reaches the end of the lookup terms then it should return to the parent table to continue lookup. I would like to store all the returned dataframes.

I imagine this could be achieved with lapply something like

```
lapply(df1$Numsdf1,function(x) lookup(x))
```

where lookup fetches the dataframe and stores the result. The problem is that this works for one level of lookup but how to I then lapply the lookup and storage for the subsequent children tables (which can be many more layers than shown here)

The result for the example above should be:

Final dataframe:

```
NumsFinal<-c("C123","C456","C789","Coo","Noo","Too","S144","S199","S743","GHS","THE","PAA"
TextFinal<-c("Harry","Bobby","Terry","Tim","Slim","Shim","Ellie","Bellie","Tellie","Front","Bunt","Shunt"
```

which I guess is just a rbind of all the rows. The problem I am having is how to apply lapply with my lookup function and ensure that the lookup is done recursively through the parent and child tables and also how to make sure that the lookup in the parent table is restarted (at the place it left) when the child lookup is complete (ie all the strings in the Nums column have been looked up)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a recursion problem. You look through all elements of the first column in a data frame. If you find a match of this name (i.e. there is a data frame in the global environment with this name) you recall the function with this new data frame and the recursion begins again. If you do not find the data frame, you simply return the data frame.

Note that the final output will be a nested list and some of the data frames appear more than once. You can use a combination of `unlist`, `do.call(rbind,..)` and `unique` to get to the final result.

**Edit:** Changed code slightly to get a more convenient data structure from the call.

```
library(tidyverse)
get_all_dfs <- function(df) {
   lapply(df[, 1], function(elem) {
      print(paste("Looking for element", elem))
      # use mget because we can use ifnotfound despite we are requesting only one element
      next_df <- mget(elem, env = .GlobalEnv, ifnotfound = NA)
      if (!is.na(next_df)) {
         unlist(get_all_dfs(next_df[[1]]), F)
      } else {
         list(setNames(df, c("col1", "col2")))
      }
    })
}

flatten_dfr(get_all_dfs(df1)) %>% unique()
```

---

So the search path will be `C123 -> Coo -> S144 -> S199 -> S743 -> Noo -> GHS -> THE -> PAA -> Too -> C456 -> C789`

Comment: Thanks @thothal. If the child is not found for a lookup then return to the parent dataframe and if so would the lookup start at the place that it left off in the parent table?

Comment: Yes that is the idea. Whenever you hit the `TRUE` part of the `if` clause, the function starts with the found data frame and loops through all the elements in the first column. Whenever it does not find a match, it returns the data frame and then continues a level above. I added some `print` statements where you will see how the algo traverses through the data (and fixed the error with recall (does not work inside the `lapply` function)

Comment: Thanks @thothal. Recursive functions are great! Just so I understand- if the lookup from a chilld dataframe returns NA then it returns to the parent dataframe? What about the other strings that havent been looked up yet in the child dataframe?

Comment: Look at the search path i added to my post: the function starts to loop through `df1`, as it finds a data frame for `C123` it starts again with the first element in `C123` and so on. When it does not find a string it returns, and then it loops through the next element. cf. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)#Recursive_procedures

Comment: OK Thanks so much @thothala and thanks for the link too. Very informative!

Comment: Sorry. Two things @thothal. Firstly shouldnt the line unlist(get_all_dfs(next_df[[1]]), F) just be unlist(get_all_dfs(next_df), F) and also how do you prevent an infinite loop. At the moment when the child table has been looked through it returns to the top of the parent table and starts the search again...Happy to ask the second question as a separate if you think that is appropriate.

Comment: 1. Well no, because `mget` returns a length 1 list with the `data.frame` as its only member. 2. It does not start the search again it continues where it has left. But did you try the code, all of your questions should become clear when you walk through the answer given.

Comment: Hi @thothal yes I tried it and it works perfectly. The problem I have is because the real tables refer to each other, which I hadnt realised so it gets caught in a loop. I've opened a new question to address this.... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54912421/how-to-prevent-infinite-loop-in-dataframe-lookup-where-elements-are-bi-direction

Comment: Ah well, in this case you will end up in an infinite loop, because the stopping criterion is that it does not find the enxt data frame. I have an very easy idea around that, will post it in the new question.