# How to prevent infinite loop in dataframe lookup where elements are bi-directional

Tags: r, search

I have a recursive function kindly explained to me by @thothal [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54906090/how-to-perform-searches-through-parent-and-child-dataframes/54907905?noredirect=1#comment96586254_54907905) This allows me to recursively get dataframes based on looking up a character string in the parent dataframe. With the example I provided this works great.

However I am now working on further tables where the elements in the child are present in the parent and vice versa. This leads to an infinte loop in the recursive function.

To repeat the original question with changes:

```
Numsdf1<-c("C123","C456","C789")
Textdf1<-c("Harry","Bobby","Terry")
df1<-data.frame(Numsdf1,Textdf1,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

The second dataframe is the result of looking up the string "C123"

```
NumsC123<-c("C123","Noo","Too")
TextC123<-c("Tim","Slim","Shim")
C123<-data.frame(NumsC123,TextC123,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

The third dataframe is a result of looking up "Coo"

```
NumsCoo<-c("S144","S199","S743")
TextCoo<-c("Ellie","Bellie","Tellie")
Coo<-data.frame(NumsCoo,TextCoo,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

The fourth is the result of looking up "Noo"

```
NumsNoo<-c("GHS","THE","PAA")
TextNoo<-c("Front","Bunt","Shunt")
Noo<-data.frame(NumsNoo,TextNoo,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

The solution originally was:

```
library(tidyverse)
get_all_dfs <- function(df) {
   lapply(df[, 1], function(elem) {
      print(paste("Looking for element", elem))
      # use mget because we can use ifnotfound despite we are requesting only one element
      next_df <- mget(elem, env = .GlobalEnv, ifnotfound = NA)
      if (!is.na(next_df)) {
         unlist(get_all_dfs(next_df[[1]]), F)
      } else {
         list(setNames(df, c("col1", "col2")))
      }
    })
}

flatten_dfr(get_all_dfs(df1)) %>% unique()
```

This means that when I run the function I get a loop which I can't break out of. So instead of the intended result of:

```
C123 -> Coo -> S144 -> S199 -> S743 -> Noo -> GHS -> THE -> PAA -> Too -> C456 -> C789
```

I get

```
C123 -> Coo -> C123 -> Coo -> C123 etc.
```

What can I do to prevent this?

### **Update 1**

I implemented the solution from @thothal. The problem I had was that the lookup function I use returns a dataframe rather than a list so I created a list to store the Global environment too. However the loop still occurs. Here is the updated code:

```
   get_all_dfs_rec <- function(df, my_env) {
        lapply(df$relatedIdEx, function(elem) {
            print(paste("Looking for element", elem))
            next_df <- myGIConcepts(elem) ###This returns a dataframe
            next_df<-list(next_df,my_env) ###Environment variable kept in a list
        if (!is.na(next_df)) {
          rm(list = elem, envir = my_env)
          unlist(get_all_dfs_rec(next_df[[1]], my_env), FALSE)
          } else {
          list(setNames(df, c("col1", "col2")))
        }
    })
  }
        
    get_all_dfs <- function(df_start) {
  ## create a new environment
  my_env <- new.env()
  ## and add all 'data.frames' from the global environment to it
  walk(ls(.GlobalEnv), ~ {
    elem <- get(.x, env = .GlobalEnv);
    if (class(elem) == "data.frame") my_env[[.x]] <- elem})
  flatten_dfr(get_all_dfs_rec(df_start, my_env)) %>% unique()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put all of your data frames in an own environment and once they are found remove it from there:

```
get_all_dfs_rec <- function(df, my_env) {
   lapply(df[, 1], function(elem) {
      print(paste("Looking for element", elem))
      # use mget because we can use ifnotfound despite we are requesting only one element
      next_df <- mget(elem, env = my_env, ifnotfound = NA)
      if (!is.na(next_df)) {
         # use list, otherwise rm tries to remove elem (which does not exist in the env)
         rm(list = elem, envir = my_env)
         unlist(get_all_dfs_rec(next_df[[1]], my_env), FALSE)
      } else {
         list(setNames(df, c("col1", "col2")))
      }
    })
}

get_all_dfs <- function(df_start) {
   ## create a new environment
   my_env <- new.env()
   ## and add all 'data.frames' from the global environment to it
   walk(ls(.GlobalEnv), ~ {
       elem <- get(.x, env = .GlobalEnv); 
       if (class(elem) == "data.frame") my_env[[.x]] <- elem})
   flatten_dfr(get_all_dfs_rec(df_start, my_env)) %>% unique()
}
```

Comment: Hi @thothal isnt there any easier way that needs less memory- I may have hundreds of dataframes to go through. Cant I keep all the elem that are used as a lookup and each time a new elem comes along check it against stored and only process if not found in the stored checking table? There may be elems in a parent-grandgrandchild table for example that are shared so Id have to keep all the dataframes

Comment: You don't lose any data frame, they are just temporarily put into an environment to keep track about which frames are already visited.

Comment: OK @thothal. I updated the code as I was using the output from my custom function which was a dataframe. I am still getting the loop though

Comment: Does it make a difference that my lookup function is returning the dataframe via a RESTful API?