# How to allow recursive function to check against previously processed strings

Tags: r

I have a recursive function that looks up a string and fetches a dataframe based on that string. Sometimes I get into infinte loops so I'd like to keep a list of all the strings that have been checked already. How can I do this? Here is the function. I want to store all of the strings called `elem`

```
 get_all_dfs_rec <- function(df, my_env) {
    lapply(df$relatedIdEx, function(elem) {    
        next_df <- myGIConcepts(elem)
        next_df_list<-list(next_df,my_env)
        if (!is.na(next_df_list)) {
          rm(list = elem, envir = my_env)
          unlist(get_all_dfs_rec(next_df_list[[1]], my_env), FALSE)
          } else {
          list(setNames(df, c("col1", "col2")))
        }
    })
  }
```

Comment: If you add more info on what you're trying to do and your data structure, it might be possible to suggest other solutions as this is an unexpected solutions approach with a recursive function nested inside an iterative loop (which is what lapply is doing).  You're working across many different environments?  The shorter reply may be to define "elem" above your get_all_dfs_rec() function as an empty list and use the <<- assignment to check/add strings already checked

Comment: Hi @Soren. The original question is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54912421/how-to-prevent-infinite-loop-in-dataframe-lookup-where-elements-are-bi-direction/54921718?noredirect=1#comment96609433_54921718 but I think there is a simpler way (and I still get the infinite loop) hence the new question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below, which initializes an empty vector and simply appends the character representation of 'elem' into the vector at each iteration.  The vector is saved in the calling function's environment, so the "<<-" operator is used to write to it from within the environment of the implied function established in lapply().  In theory, once all possible look-up names are encountered the function will eventually return NULL and pass the result of lapply up the calling chain.

```
library(tidyverse)
already_lookedup <- c()
get_all_dfs <- function(df) {
   lapply(df[, 1], function(elem) {
      print(paste("Looking for element", elem))
      if (as.character(unlist(elem)) %in% already_lookedup) {
        print(paste("Already looked up ",elem," and skipping!"))
        return (NULL)
      } else {
        already_lookedup <<- c(already_lookedup,as.character(unlist(elem)))
      }
      # use mget because we can use ifnotfound despite we are requesting only one element
      next_df <- mget(elem, env = .GlobalEnv, ifnotfound = NA)
      if (!is.na(next_df)) {
         unlist(get_all_dfs(next_df[[1]]), F)
      } else {
         list(setNames(df, c("col1", "col2")))
      }
    })
}

flatten_dfr(get_all_dfs(df1)) %>% unique()
```